# AWS CodeDeploy freezes CodePipeline stage waiting to terminate instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

One of the stages in the middle of my CodePipeline is using CodeDeploy with Blue/Green to recreate some intermediate environment. Once it is green I want to continue the pipeline without running step #4 of CodeDeploy  *(Terminate Original)*. I will run step 4 scheduled with delay of couple hours (this is basic feature of CodeDeploy).

But looks like the CodePipeline is waiting for all the steps of CodeDeploy to finish before going to the next Stage. Any idea, how to override this?

One option is to Terminate Original immediately (zero wait time), but this is not the best scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is not possible because the CodeDeploy action in CodePipeline treats a CodeDeploy deployment as an atomic unit.
- You could probably use Lambda and/or custom actions to interact with CodeDeploy directly and "split" the CodeDeploy deployment across two or more CodePipeline actions.